# Picking subset of emums using Linq (for binding w/ ComboBox

Tags: wpf, linq, enums, combobox

I have an enum

```
public enum Positions : byte
{
  Manager = 0,
  CEO = 1, 
  Lawyer =2,
  Intern =3,
  Janitor = 4,
}
```

Is it possible to get a subset of these emums to bind with a ComboBox in WPF? Say only those enum values <=2 and >= 0?  I was trying:

```
var subset = from p in Positions where p <= 2 && p >= 0 select p; 
myComboBox.ItemsSource = subset;
```

without success (Positions is flagged as error with "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern...")

I was thinking that this would be nice to use LINQ on, but if there's another simple way, that would be interesting too.
Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to get the enum values and cast it to the proper type:

```
var subset = from p in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Positions)).Cast<int>()
             where p <= 2 && p >= 0 select (Positions)p;
```

Comment: The "Cast<int>" is flagged as an error.  You have to use "Cast" on ArrayList (and other classes).  Enum.GetValues(...) returns array.  I tried forming an ArrayList from the Array without success. That would be complicated anyhow.  Thoughts?

Comment: The above code compiles fine on my machine. Did you forget to put a "using System.Linq;" at the top of your code file?

Comment: Shame on me!  That was it. Thanks  I've put "using System.Linq" in, and was able to simplify it even more to:

Comment: code is now: var subset = from p in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Positions)).Cast<Positions>() where p <= Postions.Lawyer && p >= Positions.Manager select (Positions)p;

Answer (score 0):

The last cast is unnecessary.

```
var subset = from p in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Positions)).Cast<Positions>() where p <= Postions.Lawyer && p >= Positions.Manager select p;
```